# What would be a good 2D-array alternative with the type of an own class

Tags: c++, arrays, image-processing, iteration, containers

I'm doing image processing and I'd like to make an own object out of every pixel, containing stuff like position, ID, value, etc. Now in post-processing I need to access some of these specific objects around a currently selected Pixel.

The easiest way I could imagine would be a storage like

```
PixelClass[image.rows][image.cols]
```

returning a Pointer of the object at a position. But I'm afraid this won't be easy to handle. Are there any nice alternatives, to easily access the generated objects by their position (i.e.: x,y) in C++?

EDIT:
I forgot access needs to be as fast as possible, for real-time applications

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Are you asking how to implement a 2d array efficiently in C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide a contiguous array of size `rows * cols` (e.g. using a `std::vector<T>` as member variable in your class, and have a function to calculate the index from `y * cols + x`.

Comment: you mean `y * cols + x`

Comment: @user3085931 Oops, yes.